# LEFT Join return duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query

```
SELECT
    [crm_quote_id],
    ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482) AS contactId,
    [crm_quote_company],
    [crm_quote_started_by_name],
    [crm_date_started],
    [crm_quote_status],
    [crm_quote_validity],
    [crm_quote_payment_terms],
    [address_line_1],
    [crm_quote_message_1],
    [crm_quote_message_2],
    [crm_quote_message]
FROM 
    [crmlive].[dbo].[crm_quotes] quote
LEFT JOIN 
    [CRMLiveWarwick].[dbo].[Contacts] contact 
      ON quote.address_line_1    = concat(contact.Firstname, ' ', contact.Surname)                                           
     AND quote.crm_quote_company = contact.CompanyId
```

`[CRMLiveWarwick].[dbo].[Contacts]` contact has duplicate full name (firstname + ' '+ Surname) within the same company. This means it returns more rows because they match.

I have tried to do

```
SELECT
    [crm_quote_id],
    MAX(ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482)) AS contactId,
    [crm_quote_company],
    [crm_quote_started_by_name],
    [crm_date_started],
    [crm_quote_status],
    [crm_quote_validity],
    [crm_quote_payment_terms],
    [address_line_1],
    [crm_quote_message_1],
    [crm_quote_message_2],
    [crm_quote_message]
FROM 
    [crmlive].[dbo].[crm_quotes] quote
LEFT JOIN 
    [CRMLiveWarwick].[dbo].[Contacts] contact 
      ON quote.address_line_1 = concat(contact.Firstname, ' ', contact.Surname)                                            
     AND quote.crm_quote_company = contact.CompanyId
GROUP BY 
    quote.crm_quote_id
```

So I get the max contact.Id of the duplicate contacts however I get the following error

> Column 'crmlive.dbo.crm_quotes.crm_quote_company' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Just to give some context I migrating data from old database to new database. Old database (crmlive.dbo.crm_quotes) doesn't have a contact id however I can find that out by querying the contact table which contains a firstname and surname field.

Comment: Well the error message is pretty self explanatory. You can either add a group by for all the non-aggregated columns or do something like a top 1 order by xxx type of solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use ROW_NUMBER and select the first rank. Something like this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        [crm_quote_id],
        ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482) AS ContactId,
        [crm_quote_company],
        [crm_quote_started_by_name],
        [crm_date_started],
        [crm_quote_status],
        [crm_quote_validity],
        [crm_quote_payment_terms],
        [address_line_1],
        [crm_quote_message_1],
        [crm_quote_message_2],
        [crm_quote_message],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY quote ORDER BY ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482)) AS RowNo
    FROM 
        [crmlive].[dbo].[crm_quotes] quote
    LEFT JOIN 
        [CRMLiveWarwick].[dbo].[Contacts] contact ON quote.address_line_1 = concat(contact.Firstname, ' ', contact.Surname)
                                                  AND quote.crm_quote_company = contact.CompanyId
)
SELECT cte.*        -- or better, just the columns you need
FROM cte
WHERE RowNo = 1
```

The performance might be slightly worse than grouping by all those columns, but it has the advantage of allowing to easily add more columns in the CTE without bothering about grouping them.

Also, performance-wise, you should consider avoiding JOINing VARCHARS, expecially in expressions like `quote.address_line_1 = concat(contact.Firstname, ' ', contact.Surname)` that can be quite expensive for large sets.

Comment: Gives me the following error `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Invalid column name 'quote'.` I think it talking about ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY quote ORDER BY ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482)) AS RowNo) Thanks tho

Comment: try (PARTITION BY [crm_quote_id]    that is why I asked to other question

Comment: Just validating the results

Comment: Thanks this worked any link or explanation on what `WITH cte AS ( ` and `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY quote ORDER BY ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482)) AS RowNo` is. I am just a newbie

Answer (score 4):

You need to add all these in group by clause

```
[crm_quote_company],
[crm_quote_started_by_name],
[crm_date_started],
[crm_quote_status],
[crm_quote_validity],
[crm_quote_payment_terms],
[address_line_1],
[crm_quote_message_1],
[crm_quote_message_2],
[crm_quote_message]
```

Updated query

```
SELECT
    [crm_quote_id],
    MAX(ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482)) AS contactId,
    [crm_quote_company],
    [crm_quote_started_by_name],
    [crm_date_started],
    [crm_quote_status],
    [crm_quote_validity],
    [crm_quote_payment_terms],
    [address_line_1],
    [crm_quote_message_1],
    [crm_quote_message_2],
    [crm_quote_message]
FROM [crmlive].[dbo].[crm_quotes] quote
LEFT JOIN [CRMLiveWarwick].[dbo].[Contacts] contact
    ON quote.address_line_1 = concat(contact.Firstname, ' ', contact.Surname)
    AND quote.crm_quote_company = contact.CompanyId
GROUP BY    quote.crm_quote_id,
            [crm_quote_company],
            [crm_quote_started_by_name],
            [crm_date_started],
            [crm_quote_status],
            [crm_quote_validity],
            [crm_quote_payment_terms],
            [address_line_1],
            [crm_quote_message_1],
            [crm_quote_message_2],
            [crm_quote_message]
```

Comment: This gives me the following error 
`The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.` because I use isnull which is necessary for this query

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't `join` directly on `Contact`, then, join on the `group` of contacts you want, like:

```
SELECT
    [crm_quote_id],
    max_contactId AS contactId,
    ...
FROM 
    [crmlive].[dbo].[crm_quotes] q LEFT outer JOIN 
    (select
        concat(Firstname, ' ', Surname) as contactname,
        CompanyId,
        MAX(ISNULL(Id, 2482)) AS max_contactId
     from
        [CRMLiveWarwick].[dbo].[Contacts]
     group by
        concat(Firstname, ' ', Surname), CompanyId) c ON 
     q.address_line_1 = contactname  AND 
     q.crm_quote_company = c.CompanyId
```

Comment: Gives me the following error `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
The multi-part identifier "c.Firstname" could not be bound.` It seems to be cause of `concat(c.Firstname, ' ', c.Surname), CompanyId) c`

Comment: try updated version, without aliases from other contexts

Answer (score 1):

I think the row_number will work but does this at least give you the correct
MAX(ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482))

```
SELECT
    [crm_quote_id],
    MAX(ISNULL(contact.Id, 2482)) AS contactId,
FROM 
    [crmlive].[dbo].[crm_quotes] quote
LEFT JOIN 
    [CRMLiveWarwick].[dbo].[Contacts] contact 
      ON quote.address_line_1 = concat(contact.Firstname, ' ', contact.Surname)                                            
     AND quote.crm_quote_company = contact.CompanyId
GROUP BY 
    quote.crm_quote_id
```

Comment: I need the other columns

Comment: I know you need the other columns.  But can we start with are those two columns correct?

Comment: OK not a compete answer but will try and build on it